# ¿Porqué el código siguiente no funciona?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, variables

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe porqué este código no funciona. Es un SELECT el cual, tiene un WHERE con una variable php, que es igual a una variable de javascript. El usar una variable de php en el SELECT lo vi en una pregunta de este foro, y lo de igualar una variable javascript a una php también lo vi en Stackoverflow. Llevo días intentándolo y no consigo ver el error. Muchas gracias.

```
<?php $grupo_1="General" ?>

<nav id="grupo">
  <?php echo $grupo_1 ?>
</nav>

<script>
 var grupovar = document.getElementById('grupo').textContent;
</script>

<?php 
  $grupovar = "<script> document.writeln(grupovar); </script>" ;
  $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '".$grupovar."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo $mostrar['publicacion'] 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: No creo que esto todo junto, sin espacios, funcione: `SELECT*FROM` Por otra parte, ¿si imprimes $grupovar se muestra el contenido esperado? Conviene además que establezcas control de errores en el flujo de tu código. Finalmente, nunca fue buena idea mezclar variables PHP/JavaScript, para evitar eso se creó Ajax hace ya mucho tiempo. Te recomiendo que lo uses para pasar datos del cliente al servidor en caso de que fuera necesario.

Comment: Si imprimes $grupovar si que muestra lo deseado.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error? Te recomendaría hacer un echo de `$sql` copiar el SQL y ejecutarlo directamente desde el phpmyadmin o el sistema que uses para acceder a la base de datos. No veo error en tu código, y puede ser que sea la propia información que tienes en la base de datos que no cumple la condición.

Comment: En un código tú debes controlar todo aquello que podría fallar. Revisa la respuesta donde se verifica la conexión y la ejecución de `query`.

Comment: *lo de igualar una variable javascript a una php también lo vi en Stackoverflow*, es bueno que agregues el link a la publicación donde dices haber visto eso. PHP es interpretado en el lado servidor, Javascript en el lado cliente. No puedes leer directamente una variable de JavaScript en el lado servidor o pretender que se ejecute Javascript en el servidor. Son cosas muy diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conviene controlar errores en el flujo de tu código, así podrás decidir qué hacer en esos casos, sin dejar al usuario en el limbo.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $grupovar = "<script> document.writeln(grupovar); </script>";
    if ($conexion) {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '$grupovar' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
        if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            $outPut="Datos encontrados:".PHP_EOL;
            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                $outPut.=$mostrar['publicacion'].PHP_EOL;
            } 
        } else {
            $outPut="Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
        }
    } else {
        $outPut="No hay conexión";
    }
    echo $outPut;
?>
```

Comment: Ya lo he implementado en mi código y me imprime "Datos encontrados:" pero nada más. ¿Qué debo hacer ahora con esto?

Comment: @Mariguuan parece que esa consulta no trae filas. Ponlo así: `$outPut="Datos encontrados: ".mysqli_num_rows($result);` Ahí deberá poner cuantas filas encontró. Otra posibilidad es que no haya una columna llamada `publicacion` en esa tabla.