# Ejecutar consulta SQL y mostrar resultados en base a valor de variable obtenida desde HTML mediante el método POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Necesito que cuando una respuesta sea correcta, cosa que tengo hecha y funciona, se cambie el texto del `div` grupo por la variable *grupo* (cosa que también la tengo hecha y funciona). Pero ahora viene lo complejo: quiero que muestre un contenido mediante un `SELECT`, en el que (`WHERE`) una columna llamada *grupo*, sea igual al contenido de *open2* (o lo que es lo mismo, a la variable *grupo1*) y por lo tanto al contenido del `div` *grupo*. El contenido de *open2* es aleatorio.

PD: Este es el código que se activa cuando se acierta una pregunta.

```
const grupo1 = document.getElementById('open2').textContent;
respuesta4_2.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if(respuesta44_2==respuesta_correcta_2){
                  document.getElementById('grupo').innerHTML = grupo1;
                  //Aqui se debe añadir algo que active la funcion.
                }
              });
```

Y este es el código de `SELECT` que no funciona:

```
<?php $grupovar = "<script> document.write(grupovar); </script>" ; ?>
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '".$grupovar."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $mostrar['publicacion']}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Porqué el código siguiente no funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478263/porqu%c3%a9-el-c%c3%b3digo-siguiente-no-funciona)

Comment: No repitas preguntas, en todo caso edita la original y agrega más detalles.

Comment: Pon un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta. La idea es que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema lleguen a ella fácilmente.

Comment: @padaleiana Llevas razón. Pero no sabría describir el problema.

Comment: Sugerencia: _ejecutar consulta SQL y mostrar resultados en base a valor de variable obtenida desde HTML_. Algo así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor y no se entera de lo que pasa en el cliente (navegador), a menos que haya una petición de por medio, ya sea "normal" (recargando la página) o por AJAX y creo que esta última opción es la que necesitas.

Tal como lo tienes ahora:

```
<?php $grupovar = "<script> document.write(grupovar); </script>" ; ?>
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '".$grupovar."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
```

Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '<script> document.write(grupovar); </script>' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1
```

Aparte del error de tener `SELECT*FROM` (debería haber espacio antes y después del asterisco), dudo que el valor que estás buscando realmente contenga una etiqueta *script* y, además, PHP no tiene un intérprete de Javascript para obtener el valor que esperas, recuerda, eso pasa en el navegador.

Entonces, en el navegador debes tomar el valor deseado y ejecutar una [petición AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) para obtener el nuevo contenido:

```
respuesta4_2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Esto debe estar dentro de la petición
    const grupo1 = document.getElementById('open2').textContent;
    if(respuesta44_2==respuesta_correcta_2){
        // Crear objeto para enviar datos
        let data = { grupo: grupo1 };
        // Ver lo que se va a enviar
        console.log(data);
        // Asegúrate de poner la URL correcta para el archivo PHP
        fetch('ruta/script.php', {
            // Ejecutar petición con método POST
            method: 'post',
            // Enviar variable con su valor correspondiente
            body: data
        }).then(res => {
            // Analizar resultado de petición
            if(res.ok) {
                // Todo salió bien, interpretar resultado
                return res.text();
            }
            // Hubo error, lanzar excepción
            throw res.statusText;
        }).then(resp => {
            // Actualizar texto en contenedor con respuesta del servidor
            document.getElementById('grupo').innerHTML = resp;
        }).catch(error => {
            // Algo falló, mostrar mensaje de error en consola
            console.log('Error en petición AJAX: ' + error.message);
        });
    }
});
```

Finalmente, en tu script PHP (el mismo que debes especificar en la ruta de `fetch()`):

```
<?php
// No olvides primero conectar a base de datos

// Primero obtienes el valor a buscar en $_POST
$grupovar = $_POST['grupo'] ?? ''; // Si no existe la variable, se asigna cadena vacía
// Define una variable para devolver resultado
$resultado = 'No se encontró un valor adecuado';

// Verifica que hay un valor a buscar
if($grupovar != '') {
    // Solo necesitas un campo, no es necesario cargar todo con *
    $sql = "SELECT publicacion FROM publicaciones WHERE  grupo = '$grupovar' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // Lee la consulta, solo es un resultado, no necesitas un ciclo
    if($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // Actualiza la variable para devolver resultados
        $resultado = $mostrar['publicacion'];
    } else {
        // La consulta no encontró coincidencias
        $resultado = "No se encontraron resultados para <b>$grupovar</b>";
    }
}
// Finalmente, envías el resultado al navegador
echo $resultado;
```

Probando lo que se envía:

```js
respuesta4_2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Esto debe estar dentro de la petición
    const grupo1 = document.getElementById('open2').textContent;
    // Crear objeto para enviar datos
    let data = { grupo: grupo1 };
    // Ver lo que se va a enviar
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<button id="respuesta4_2">Click aquí!</button>
<div id="open2">valor del grupo</div>
```

Comment: cuando lo ejecuto me dice que no se encontro un valor adecuado. ¿Por qué puede ser? Además, no entiendo por qué de $_POST{'grupo'] pones dos interrogaciones y dos comillas.

Comment: @Mariguuan, modifiqué la respuesta para que muestre otro mensaje si la consulta no encontró coincidencias. En cuanto a los `?? '';` es una característica de PHP a partir de la versión 7: [Operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: @Muchisimas gracias por todo.

Comment: Perdona por volver a molestarte. Pero, pese a haber modificado el código, me sigue diciendo que no se encontró un valor adecuado. He comprobado todo y no veo nada mal. Tras revisar múltiples veces el código, he llegado a la conclusión de que el problema es que no se envía la variable $_POST['grupo1'] mediante fetch. He comprobado que el url este bien escrito, he ido tanteando para ver donde estaba el fallo y nada. No encuentro ninguna solución.

Comment: @Mariguuan, actualicé la respuesta, había olvidado que el valor se va modificando y debes tomarlo dentro de la función para asegurar que está actualizado. También se muestra en consola lo que se va a enviar.

Comment: Lo siento mucho. Debo ser gilipoyas, pero me sigue dando el mismo problema. En la consola pone {grupo: grupo1}, que es lo que deberia poner pero luego parece que no lo obtiene con post. Además, cuando no tengo la consola abierta cuando lo activo, esta, la consola, me da un object y tal.

Comment: @Mariguuan, agregué un código ejecutable al final de la pregunta para demostrar cómo se debe ver en consola el valor a enviar. Si no te aparece igual que aquí, tal vez tienes otro problema en el código, como que el contenedor de donde tomas el texto no sea correcto.